# angular-leaflet-directive : loading spinner in leaflet when load layer

Tags: angular-leaflet-directive

Using the AngularJS leaflet directive, I want to load a layer inside an already-displayed leaflet. My problem is how to create a loading bar/spinner inside leaflet when loading the layer?

Comment: Please refer to http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve